# Solutions of hypergeometric equation when $c\in\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, special-functions, hypergeometric-function

Let $E(a,b,c;z)$ be the hypergeometric differential equation
$$
z(1-z)w''+(c-(a+b+z)z)w'-abw
$$
with $w$ the unknown.
It is well known that if $z\notin\mathbb{Z}$, then $E(a,b,c;z)$ has linearly independent solutions around $z=0$
$$
{}_2F_1(a,b,c;z) \quad\text{and}\quad z^{1-c}{}_2F_1(1+a-c,1+b-c,2,c;z)
$$
with ${}_2F_1$ the hypergeometric function.

Now, how about the case $c\in\mathbb{Z}$?
Of course, we can theoretically solve the equation by using the method of Frobenius, but I would like to know explicit expressions (if there exists any explicit expression). I would also like to know the monodromies.

Comment: https://dlmf.nist.gov/15.10.E3 gives an explicit form for the second function

Comment: Thank you for showing me the URL. It helps me a lot.